# Start Selenium Hub and Node using ProcessBuilder.java - port error

Tags: java, swing, selenium

I have Swing front end for use as a client to kick off Selenium tests.  At the point where I kick off the test process, the first thing I do is fire up a local Selenium hub and node using the following code:

```
    String[] nodeCmd = new String[]{"java", "-jar", "selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar", "-role node", "-nodeConfig config\\DefaultNode.json"};
    ProcessBuilder pbNode = new ProcessBuilder(nodeCmd);
    pbNode.directory(new File("C:\\selenium\\"));
    File nodeLog = new File("C:\\selenium\\logs\\nodeOut.log");
    pbNode.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pbNode.redirectOutput(nodeLog);
    Process nodeP = pbNode.start();

    String[] hubCmd = new String[]{"java", "-jar", "selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar", "-role hub", "-hubConfig config\\DefaultHub.json"};
    ProcessBuilder pbHub = new ProcessBuilder(hubCmd);
    pbHub.directory(new File("C:\\selenium\\"));
    File hubLog = new File("C:\\selenium\\logs\\hubOut.log");
    pbHub.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pbHub.redirectOutput(hubLog);
    Process hubP = pbHub.start();
```

Whilst the hub is started up correctly, when the node process is started it seems to be doing so as a hub (log output is exactly the same) with the result that it complains the port is already in use.

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Selenium is already running on port 4444. Or some other service is.
>       at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.start(SeleniumServer.java:491)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:300)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(SeleniumServer.java:245)
>       at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:96)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  I have checked the config files and they are definitely right.

**Update**

So I finally worked out what I was doing wrong!  My mistake is in the way I was constructing my Array of parameters to pass into the ProcessBuilder constructor.

Wrong:

```
String[] nodeCmd = new String[]{"java", "-jar", "selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar", "-role node", "-nodeConfig config\\DefaultNode.json"};
```

Right:

```
String[] nodeCmd = new String[]{"java", "-jar", "selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar", "-role",  "node", "-nodeConfig", "config\\DefaultNode.json"};
```

I wan't splitting the key string and value string for the role and config params.  Grrr!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your nodeConfig.json is using the `"port"` property of an unused port (defaults to `5555`), and make sure that in your hubConfig.json, it is using the `"port"` property of an unused port (defaults to `4444`)

If you can validate that the above are both correct, then the only other issue that i can imagine, is that the previous hubs (probably started up when testing this very functionality) were left open.

I would ensure that all `java.exe` processes are terminated, and add a failsafe in your code to quit the grid.

Comment: Having fiddled around a bit, the hub always listens on port 4444 regardless of whether I change it's config to listen on a different port.  That kind of indicates that both processes are ignoring my config json files.  The path is definitely right.  Really not sure what is going on here.